Is it recommended to store common combinations of lookup table IDs is a separate table that is then referenced by a T2 SCD versioning table?
Using the basis of a type 2 slowly changing dimension table I've put together this simplistic example of sports match with stats:



Match_Key
Match_Id
Stat_1
Stat_2
Stat_3
Effective_Date
Current_Flag




1
1
10
5

2000-01-01T00:00:00
N


2
1
15
5

2000-01-02T00:00:00
N


3
1
10
5

2000-01-03T00:00:00
Y


4
2
10
5

2000-02-01T00:00:00
Y


5
3
10
5

2000-02-02T00:00:00
Y


6
4
10
5

2000-02-03T00:00:00
Y



Few things to note in the table above:

There are actually around 30 stats within the real table and a lot of them can frequently be Null
The table is 4m+ records
The combination of stats values repeats both i) infrequently within match versions (as corrections are made and then re-corrected) - see Match_Key_Ids 1 and 3 and ii) very frequently between matches, e.g. Match_Key_Ids 1, 3, 4, 5 and 6

I was wondering if it was good practice to save some space in the table and create a new table with stat value combinations:



Stat_Combo_Id
Stat_1
Stat_2
Stat_3




1
10
5



2
15
5




And then create a FK to this table:



Match_Key
Match_Id
Stat_Combo_Id
Effective_Date
Current_Flag




1
1
1
2000-01-01T00:00:00
N


2
1
2
2000-01-02T00:00:00
N


3
1
1
2000-01-03T00:00:00
Y


4
2
1
2000-02-01T00:00:00
Y


5
3
1
2000-02-02T00:00:00
Y


6
4
1
2000-02-03T00:00:00
Y



I've not been able to find any posts easily with this kind of structure which makes me think it isn't commonly used and perhaps I'm missing some major drawback(s)?

if it was good practice to save some space in the table Any change must either solve some task or have some purpose. The task/purpose "Save some space" applied to the database is usually unreasonable in itself.
